# Python Global Variable Definition Trouble Shooting

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, global-variables

I have a function that is converting ECEF into Lat Lon, and I don't understand why Python is complaining that none of the variables are declared. For example, it initially complains that variables `asp` and `esp` are not declared, yet I can plainly see that they are not but two lines higher.

```
import math


def main():

    x = 504722.144
    y = -488562.32
    z = 4059321.82
    a = 6378137.0
    e = 8.1819190842622e-2
    asp = math.pow(a,2)
    esp = math.pow(e,2)

    b = math.sqrt(asq * (1-esp))
    bsq = math.pow(b,2)
    ep=math.sqrt((asq-bsq/bsq))
    p = math.sqrt(math.pow(x,2) + math.pow(y,2))
    th = math.atan2(a*z, b*p)
    lon = math.atan2(y,x)
    lat = math.atan2((z+math.pow(ep,2)*b*math.pow(math.sin(th),3)), (p- esq*a*Math.pow(Math.cos(th),3)))
    N = a/(math.sqrt(1-esq*math.pow(math.sin(lat),2)))
    alt = p / math.cos(lat) - N
    lon = lon % (2*math.pi)
    ret = [lat, lon, alt]
    print ret

    return ret
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `'asq' != 'asp'`...

Comment: Where did you exactly define `asq`?

Comment: You need to learn to [mind your Ps and Qs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_your_Ps_and_Qs) :)

Comment: *sigh* So true, I actually caught the error and was desperately trying to rush back and fix it before anyone noticed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"For example, it initially complains that variables asp an esp are not declared...yet I can plainly see that they are not but two lines higher. "

You have a typo there. asp != asq, therefore 'asq' is unknown.